# Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a byte allocation with free bytes and until OOM"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a game app. I have 3 activities (intro, game/main and gameover). The game works fine on first to third attempts, but by the fourth time trying to retry (there is a button to retry at the the gameover activity that sends you back to the main activity), I get this error:
E/art: throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 27581052 byte allocation with 7416608 free bytes and until OOM"

I already tried to:
1) resize the images/bitmaps I work with;
2) place the images in different drawable folders like xhdpi, xxxhdpi (and all in between...);
3) adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` and `android:largeHeap="true"` to the manifest;
And all of those just bought me some more retry attempts, but did not resolve the problem (the app gets the same error message after 8~10 attempts).

I also tried these, since I found them on some answers here in this forum:
4) implementing ComponentCallbacks2 onTrimMemory (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html) on the gameover or main activities;
5) putting something like this on gameover or main activities:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      
}
```

And those had no change at all on my problem...

Here is the Logcat:

```
04-26 00:22:39.665 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:22242888
04-26 00:22:39.755 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2897(97KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 121MB/128MB, paused 548us total 6.523ms
04-26 00:22:39.775 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 137MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.775 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1719(109KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 121MB/128MB, paused 394us total 13.719ms
04-26 00:22:39.795 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 136MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.795 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1089(84KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 120MB/128MB, paused 473us total 21.972ms
04-26 00:22:39.795 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 26MB allocation
04-26 00:22:39.815 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 136MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.815 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(384B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 120MB/128MB, paused 386us total 17.719ms
04-26 00:22:39.815 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 27581052 byte allocation with 7416672 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
04-26 00:22:39.825 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 136MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.825 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 120MB/128MB, paused 387us total 7.547ms
04-26 00:22:39.845 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 136MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.845 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 120MB/128MB, paused 368us total 17.285ms
04-26 00:22:39.845 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 26MB allocation
04-26 00:22:39.855 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 136MB to 128MB
04-26 00:22:39.855 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 120MB/128MB, paused 551us total 17.798ms
04-26 00:22:39.855 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 27581052 byte allocation with 7416608 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
04-26 00:22:39.855 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
04-26 00:22:39.855 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-26 00:22:39.865 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp, PID: 31000
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 27581052 byte allocation with 7416608 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:469)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:501)
        at com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp.FlyingDactylView.<init>(FlyingDactylView.java:57)
        at com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
04-26 00:22:39.875 31000-31000/com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31000 SIG: 9
```

And here is the gameover activity:

```
package com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp;

import ...

public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

        int score = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get("POPOINTS");
        Button startGameAgain = findViewById(R.id.play_again_btn);
        TextView displayScore = findViewById(R.id.displayScore);
        TextView displayRecord = findViewById(R.id.displayRecord);


        //update record
        SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences("RECORD", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int record = settings.getInt("RECORD", 0);

        String score1;
        String record1;
        if (score > record) {
            record = score;
            record1 = Integer.toString(record);
            score1 = Integer.toString(score);
            displayScore.setText(String.format("POPOINTS = %s", score1));
            displayRecord.setText(String.format("*NEW RECORD* = %s", record1));


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("RECORD", record);
            editor.apply();
        }
        else {
            record1 = Integer.toString(record);
            score1 = Integer.toString(score);
            displayScore.setText(String.format("POPOINTS = %s", score1));
            displayRecord.setText(String.format("record = %s", record1));
        }


        startGameAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent (GameOverActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });



    }


}
```

And here is the main activity:

```
package com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp;

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FlyingDactylView gameView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static long Interval = 30;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameView = new FlyingDactylView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      gameView.invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, Interval);
    }


}
```

and here is the view used by the main activity:

```
package com.example.theflyingdactylgameapp;

import ...
public class FlyingDactylView extends View {

    private Bitmap dactyl[] = new Bitmap[2];
    private int dactylX = 10;
    private int dactylY;
    private int dactylSpeed;

    private int canvasWidth, canvasHeight;

    private int popo0X, popo0Y, popo0Speed = 16;
    private int popo2X, popo2Y, popo2Speed = 18;
    private int popo1X, popo1Y, popo1Speed = 20;
    private Bitmap popo[] = new Bitmap[2];

    private int redX, redY, redSpeed = 24;
    private int red1X, red1Y, red1Speed = 27;
    private Bitmap redBall;

    private int score, lifeCounterOfDactyl;

    private boolean touch = false;

    private Bitmap backgroundImage;
    private Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap life[] = new Bitmap[2];

    // creating sound
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int sound1, sound2, sound3;


    // criando objetos na tela
    public FlyingDactylView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        dactyl[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dactyl1);
        dactyl[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dactyl2);

        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);

        popo[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.popo1);

        popo[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.popo2);

        redBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_ball);

        scorePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        scorePaint.setTextSize(70);
        scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        scorePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        life[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.egg);
        life[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.broken_egg);

        dactylY = 550;
        score = 0;
        lifeCounterOfDactyl = 3;

        // creating sound player and placing sounds
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build();
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(5)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .build();
        }
        else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }
        sound1 = soundPool.load(this.getContext(), R.raw.fly, 1);
        sound2 = soundPool.load(this.getContext(), R.raw.pick_popo, 1);
        sound3 = soundPool.load(this.getContext(), R.raw.red_hit, 1);




    }
    // movimentos
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage,0, 0, null);

        // movimentos dactyl
        int minDactylY = dactyl[0].getHeight();
        int maxDactylY = canvasHeight - dactyl[0].getHeight() * 3;
        dactylY += dactylSpeed;
        if (dactylY < minDactylY) {
            dactylY = minDactylY;
        }
        if (dactylY > maxDactylY) {
            dactylY = maxDactylY;
        }
        dactylSpeed += 2;

        if (touch) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(dactyl[1], dactylX, dactylY, null);
            touch = false;
        }
        else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(dactyl[0], dactylX, dactylY, null);
        }


        // movimentos popó
        popo0X -= popo0Speed;

        if (hitPopoChecker(popo0X, popo0Y)) {
            score += 10;
            popo0X = -100;
            // sound when hit popo0
            soundPool.play(sound2, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);
        }

        if (popo0X < 0) {
            popo0X = canvasWidth + 21;
            popo0Y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDactylY - minDactylY)) + minDactylY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(popo[0], popo0X, popo0Y, null);



        // movimentos popó2
        popo2X -= popo2Speed;

        if (hitPopoChecker(popo2X, popo2Y)) {
            score += 10;
            popo2X = -100;
            // sound when hit popo2
            soundPool.play(sound2, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);
        }

        if (popo2X < 0) {
            popo2X = canvasWidth + 21;
            popo2Y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDactylY - minDactylY)) + minDactylY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(popo[0], popo2X, popo2Y, null);


        // movimentos popó gordo
        popo1X -= popo1Speed;

        if (hitPopoChecker(popo1X, popo1Y)) {
            score += 20;
            popo1X = -100;
            // sound when hit popo gordo
            soundPool.play(sound2, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);
        }

        if (popo1X < 0) {
            popo1X = canvasWidth + 21;
            popo1Y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDactylY - minDactylY)) + minDactylY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(popo[1], popo1X, popo1Y, null);


        // movimentos Red Ball
        redX -= redSpeed;

        if (hitPopoChecker(redX, redY)) {
            redX = -100;
            lifeCounterOfDactyl--;
            // sound when hit red ball 1
            soundPool.play(sound3, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);

            if (lifeCounterOfDactyl == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
                // free up resources from sound on Game Over by red ball 1
                soundPool.release();
                soundPool = null;

                gameOverIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                gameOverIntent.putExtra("POPOINTS", score);
                getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
            }
        }

        if (redX < 0) {
            redX = canvasWidth + 21;
            redY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDactylY - minDactylY)) + minDactylY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(redBall, redX, redY, null);

        // movimentos Red Ball2
        red1X -= red1Speed;

        if (hitPopoChecker(red1X, red1Y)) {
            red1X = -100;
            lifeCounterOfDactyl--;
            // sound when hit red ball 1
            soundPool.play(sound3, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);

            if (lifeCounterOfDactyl == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
                // free up resources from sound on Game Over by red ball 2
                soundPool.release();
                soundPool = null;

                gameOverIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                gameOverIntent.putExtra("POPOINTS", score);
                getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
            }
        }

        if (red1X < 0) {
            red1X = canvasWidth + 21;
            red1Y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDactylY - minDactylY)) + minDactylY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(redBall, red1X, red1Y, null);




        // Score
        canvas.drawText("Popoints: " + score, 20, 60, scorePaint);

        // life counter
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            int x = (int) (700 + life[0].getWidth() * 1.9 * i);
            int y = 10;

            if (i < lifeCounterOfDactyl) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(life[0], x, y, null);
            }
            else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(life[1], x, y, null);
            }
        }



    }

    public Boolean hitPopoChecker (int x, int y) {
        if (dactylX < x && x < (dactylX + dactyl[0].getWidth()) && dactylY < y && y < (dactylY + dactyl[0].getHeight())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touch = true;
            // decrease here to make Dactyl goes faster
            dactylSpeed = -22;
            // sound when tap to fly
            soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any advice on how to try and solve it will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *"I can't post my questions because I always get the message "this looks like spam". What should I do?"* Go to the [**Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read some of the articles, e.g. this would be a good start: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does the `FlyingDactylView` constructor do that uses so much memory? Since the stacktrace clearly shows the error happening there, don't you think it would be helpful to post that code, rather than the unrelated `GameOverActivity` code you did post?

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, I just posted it too. Sorry I'm still learning how it works...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a timer task in MainActivity.onCreate, it keeps a reference to the activity. That reference can be never cleared because the timer thread never stops, so the memory used for the activity can never be reclaimed and reused. This is called a memory leak.

You need to keep a reference to the timer in the activity and cancel the timer in onDestroy.

Comment: Hi @Joni, thank you for your answer. I've been trying for the last hour to do it, but unfortunately I'm still new at this and I couldn't figure out how to do it properly.... I'm supposing I should keep that timer on until the gameover activity, since if I canceled it when I went back to the MainActivity, the game would not draw my images every 30 milliseconds. Everything I was taking for the gameover activity up to now came from the gameview linked to the MainActivity, so I can't seem to pass data (nor have I any idea of what exactly I'd pass) for that activity... I'll keep trying tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, so I created a boolean variable and a method in MainActivity to set this boolean to false. I also put an "if" statement triggered by that boolean to clear the timer using `timer.cancel();` and `timer.purge();`, and created a new timer to put the game in motion right before the `timer.schedule`. I invoked that method at the GameOver activity's onCreate... But I noticed no change at all, I'm still getting the same  memory error at the same retry attempt. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are starting a *new instance* of the main activity from game over activity. The old instance is still on the stack, it has not been destroyed, and you could return to it with the back button (unless you've done something to prevent that) - you may want to use the intent flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and review the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Another thing to think about is, should this timer be running while the user is in some other app and your game is in the background? Probably not